# Ubuntu 22.04 will randomly stop playing sound through notebook speakers

Tags: sound

I am a beginner Linux user, and for a few days I'm having an issue.
I boot the system and start playing audio while working on projects, the sound comes out fine for a while, but then suddenly stops. It shows in audio settings as if it's still working, but only works via headphones, not via the speakers. If I reboot, it always for work for a while (from 30s to a few hours) but usually stops.
I noticed that it usually coincides with another issue, which is the system turn off immediatly if I remove the charger, but I'm not sure if the two are related.
Can anyone suggest a solution? Apologies if this turn out to be a simple issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I got it working again by following the instructions here
https://tutonics.com/articles/fix-no-sound-turn-off-auto-mute-in-ubuntu-1210/

I then ran

```
sudo alsactl store
```

Auto-mute is to automatically mute speakers when headphones are plugged in (at least I think this is the purpose).
I did not plug headphones in, I was just watching YouTube vids and it would cut out usually after about 15 mins. So possible a heat issue causing the laptop to think headphone is plugged in? I have no idea but when I toggle this setting sound works again.

I'm not sure if this is a permanent fix but so far it works. I hope it helps you too.

Edit: Sounds stopped midway through a 45 minute YT vid again. I got it back by running alsamixer and toggling the auto-mute on then off again. So looks like this a workaround but not a permanent fix.